# Why is the expression 'at work' not 'on work'?

Tags: prepositions

It is written everywhere that the person is "at " work. He is "at" work.
So why we can't use  "on" instead of "at" there?
We use on Monday ,on Tuesday etc
I know this is the rule but what if we use "on" work.
Why it is wrong?

Comment: The preposition "at" is typically used to denote a location (a specific position) where it takes a noun phrase as object complement, as in "at the dentist", at "school", It's the same with "at work" where locative "at" has noun "work" as its complement.

Comment: @Alan - _in the park vs at the park_ might be a duplicate of [Meaning 1](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+work), but that question doesn't touch on [Meaning 2](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+work), i.e.: _working [at something]; busy [with something]. (See also_ at play *)*.

Comment: @J.R. If you think that the OP is inquiring about Meaning 2, you're in the minority. But I guess you could ask them if that's what they had in mind. That might be easier than writing multiple comments pointing out Meaning 2.

Comment: @Alan - I don't think the OP is asking about Meaning 2 or Meaning 1. I think they are simply asking about the phrase in general, and I think both meanings are deserving of attention.

Comment: @Aryendu When you say *at work*, are you referring to *at work* as a preposition of place. In other words, *Joe is not at home, he is at work*?

Comment: If its not preposition of place, then will it be correct?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that, as with most "why" question about language, the **whole** of the answer is:

> Because that's how English is.

There is no other answer.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is correct, and there really is nothing else to be said on the matter.

Comment: This ignores general rules that can describe preposition usage. It's not *entirely* arbitrary.

Comment: @chepner If you think there are general rules that can describe preposition usage in English, you are wrong. They are not general rules. More often than not, they are random rules that can only be explained using the word **coincidence**. I think this post answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the distinction arises because "work" is a physical location, while "Monday" is a point in time.

---

In general, the correct preposition to use is often determined by subtle distinctions in the "category" of the thing the preposition operates on. For instance, "small" units of time tend to take "on", while "large" units of time take "in":

- The clock chimes *on* the hour.
- I will go to work *on* Monday.
- I went to the beach *in* July.
- I will go to Europe *in* 2017.

For physical locations, we use "in", "on", or "at" (among other possibilities), depending on what the location is.

- I am *in* the store.  (Emphasizing the physical structure of the store.)
- I am *at* the store.  (Emphasizing that you are in one place rather than somewhere else.)
- I am *at* work.       ("Work" is an idea, not necessarily any specific place.)
- I work *in* an office.  (An office is indoors.)
- I work *on* a construction site. (A construction site is typically outdoors.)

And just to reassure you that English is not completely logical, you can use *at* with either of the last two sentences. Sometimes, a language just accepts some usage as correct while rejecting others.

Comment: But the clock chimes **at** seven o'clock.

Comment: I thought of that, too. I wonder if "on" was a bad example here, or at least my small/large was the wrong rule to describe. Another rule(?) might be "use *at* for a single *time*, but use *on* for a single *date*"?

Comment: This describes only one usage of "at work," and doesn't account for, say, the street sign "Men at Work", which describes an action, not a location. Similarly, I can say, "The cancer researchers are hard at work on a cure," and not be referring to where they are analyzing their lab tests.

Comment: In the movie "Carrie" by Brian De Palma there is a scene in which a Bible-thumping mother of the eponymous Carrie visits one of her friend's mother and she says "I'm here on the Lord's work". Seemed relevant to this post. In this case IMO "on" is a preposition which means "engaged in" which has different meaning that being in the place in which the work is being carried out.